# Spring OAuth - No qualifying bean of type PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I was successfully able to integrate OAuth2 to my previous application (a REST service) by replacing BASIC auth.

Then I got the following exception:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManagerDB2,transactionManager
```

When I remove the bean `transactionManagerDB2` it started to working fine.
I have 2 transaction managers because I have 2 connected databases.

Since I have a `InMemoryTokenStore`, I'm curious about the require of a `TransactionManager`. (And why Oauth is not able pick up "transactionManager" by default name)

Somehow I have configured a CustomeUserDetailService via  `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){}`, which was working fine before and now with a single TransactionManager.

I used [sparklr-boot](https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot) Spring Boot application to integrate OAuth with my application.
(Thanks to [Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer) to make such simple easy to understand example)

I'm using:

- Spring 4.2.5
- Spring Security 4.0.4
- Spring OAuth 2.0.9
- (No Spring Boot)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that methods in DefaultTokenServices are annotated with @Transactional. So even if you're not using a database, you'll need to add a transaction manager bean like this in your authorization server configuration:

```
@Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourceTransactionManager() {
            @Override
            public Object getResourceFactory() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition) throws TransactionException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void commit(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {

            }

            @Override
            public void rollback(TransactionStatus status) throws TransactionException {

            }
        };
    }
```